# Is there a 'Rake-like' design pattern?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, rake

If you had a library / framework / class implementing something like Rake's dependency management it seems like it would be useful for general purpose programming, ie by breaking code up into tasks and dependencies.

eg, Imagine an app for managing a users photo library on flickr. The app might be broken down into Rake-like tasks with interdependencies. Logging in might be one task, syncing the users photos might be another task that depended on the logging in task, deleting a photo might be a task that depended on the user's data being upto date.

This seems like a simple/(fundamental) concept that may already exist as a Design Pattern or even as a library (ideally in c or objective-c), unless it is a really bad idea.. (please comment)?

Would this be reinventing the wheel to implement Rake in Objective-c (or your language of choice) for use internally in a desktop app, instead of as a build utility?

Comment: that is pretty vague. Something like Rake which differs from Rake how, exactly, while having which similarities?

Comment: Do you know what Rake does? Imagine that, not as a build utility, but as the central architecture of, say, a desktop app, like say, photoshop. My question is simply is this already a recognised design pattern? sorry you find it vague.

Comment: Yes, I know what it does, but I don't see what you mean by "as the central architecture". What exactly would its role be? What you're asking is basically "is there anything like an orange, for transporting people between to and from work?" Yes, there *might* be. But they're fundamentally different things, and it's not clear to anyone who doesn't live in your head *how* one would do the job of the other. I could draw out a dozen of parallels between the two, but I have no clue which specific ones *you* are interested in.

Comment: It's role would be similar to Rake's - to manage dependent tasks. I'm sure that really you understand this. Do you sincerely think that "Is there a name for what Rake does?" is similar to "is there anything like an orange, for transporting people between to and from work?". Some people might think this makes you sound like a dick.

Comment: truth to be told, the original version of your question wasn't very clear. Being interested myself in this kind of things, I just did a bit of educated guesswork, but I wasn't at all sure what you were talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're talking about is the actual *dependency management*, I wouldn't call it a design pattern.

Read about how to do a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), dependency management boils down to that.

I think it's highly possible that such a library exists.

**Edit**

I just found [this library](http://google.com/codesearch#TGnW1KjhbLE/trunk/CDTopoSortNode.m&type=cs), it might prove useful. Actually it's a fairly large library, but it contains a class that does (or claims it can do) the topological sorting.

I should add that I'm pretty sure there isn't a design pattern that deals with this. Figuring out in which order a given sequence of interdependent tasks should be completed is just a graph theory problem. The wikipedia articles I linked contain pretty much everything you need to know.

Shouldn't that class work, I figure it wouldn't be difficult to implement it from scratch, or by translating from another language (Python for instance: I seem to recall that [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) provides you with such a capability).

**Even more edit**

I don't think implementing dependency management in your app would be just another case of wheel reinvention. If you need it, code it. That is, unless you can find a generic, working library with a compatible license that suits your need. In that case, by all means use it. It really is that simple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @s.m. I was very much thinking of representing tasks as DAG nodes, managing the execution of them and keeping track of their state. Nodes would have properties relating to caching behaviour, reset conditions, asynchronous/synchronous execution, etc. This would pretty much be a naive re-implementation of Rake - which is fine (and not too difficult for me to tackle), as long as i'm not overlooking an existing strategy/design for such a thing that is tried and tested and written by cleverer people than me. Very interesting that Twisted can maybe do this.